# MySQL database setup help

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I am making a classifieds website...
I have these 6 tables:
Every category has sub-categories (or options) which you can see below.

Lets say the user wants to post a classified, and has entered all info into the forms necessary, and I am at the stage where I have to create the PHP code to actually INSERT the data into the database.

I am thinking something like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO classifieds (classified_id, ad_id, poster_id, cat_id, area_id, headline, description) VALUES ($classified_id, '$ad_id', $poster_id, $cat_id, $area_id, '$headline', '$description')");
```

But I don't know where to take it from here...
I think the posters table should not be like this, because how should I determine what the `poster_id` should be? Or should I set it to `auto-increment`?
Remember this, posters may not log in or anything, so there is no problem with one person having multiple poster_table records if you know what I mean.

`classified_id` is a random unique value generated by PHP so that is always unique.

Please guide me! I don't know how to link the tables together correctly.

If you have any Q let me know and I will update this Q!

```
category table:
cat_id (PK)
cat_name

category_options table:
option_id (PK)
cat_id (FK)
option_name

option_values table:
value_id (PK)
option_id (FK)
value

classifieds table:
classified_id (PK)
ad_id (VARCHAR) something like "Bmw330ci_28238239832" which will appear in URL
poster_id (FK)
cat_id (FK)
area_id (FK)
headline
description
price
etc....

posters table:
poster_id (PK)
name 
email
tel
password

area table:
area_id (PK)
area
community
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea already. When someone creates a post, and enters their personal info, FIRST insert the "poster" record into the posters table. The "poster_id" primary key for that table should be an auto_increment field.

Next, get the ID of the new poster you just created using PHP's "mysql_insert_id". That integer value will be the number you put in the "poster_id" foreign key field in the "classifieds" table.

Answer (score 0):

You should usually set the primary key to an auto-increment field.

When you have linked tables and you need to join on the id, you can first insert into the main table and then use the function [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to retrieve the id of the element you just inserted. You can then insert into the other table using this value as the foreign key.

This is a very standard way to do things, so it should be fine for you.

Comment: But I have a primary key in every table, do they all have to be AI?

Comment: They don't have to be, but it's almost always a good idea to have the primary key as an auto-increment. One obvious exception is when you have an intermediate table, then you only need the two foreign keys and no extra column for the primary key. I don't think you have such a table in your schema though, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: so in my case what would you set to primary? I mean the cat_id couldn't be PK right? because there are 15 categories I have which are constant (ie, set by me, non-changeable)...

Comment: If you've defined some fixed ID's in your code then you can use those as a primary key, but if there's any chance ever that you might have to change those ids then it wouldn't hurt to add an extra column with an auto-increment id as the PK and use that in all joins. Changing a PK once your system is live is a painful experience. You should avoid using a PK that might one day need to change.